# increase font size exclusively of children of an element

Tags: html, css

I'm using rems to set the sizes of fonts, and at certain breakpoints I wanted to scale the size of the the fonts but not the whole page just texts within a certain container. I know that if I change the font-size of `html` it will change the size of all elements on the page, but how can I only change the size of children within a certain container, eg. `.container` in my example below, Is this possible? **I want to scale the container as a whole and not specifiy a size for each child.** :

**CSS**

```
html{
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  p{
    font-size:1rem;
    }

h1{
font-size:2rem;
}

.container{
   font-size:3rem;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Main title</h1>
<p>Main text</p>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to set the font-size of <p> to something different when it is in `.container`?

Comment: Did you try `.container h1, .container p`?

Comment: yes I tried that of course, but I don't want to set each child individually, jus the scale the container as whole

Comment: try `.container *` as your selector

Answer (score 2):

Use `selector *` to target all children:

```css
html {
  font-size: 13px;
}
p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.container * {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main title</h1>
<p>Main text</p>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cfLshc9a/1/)**

```
.container h1{
     font-size:3rem;
     color:red;
}
```

Comment: yes I tried that of course, but I don't want to set each child individually, jus the scale the container as  a whole

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to set a specific `<p>` in a specific `.container` by doing this:

```
.container p {
    font-size:10px;
}

.container2 p {
    font-size:15px;
}
```

The

font-size will be different in each container.

Comment: yes I tried that of course, but I don't want to set each child individually, just the scale the container as whole

Comment: Try the solution sideroxylon said in the question comments.